# WSO2 Identity Server XACML Request giving Indeterminate Response

Tags: wso2, xacml, wso2-identity-server

I am using the sample policy at:

> https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/trunk/commons/balana/modules/balana-core/src/test/resources/basic/3/policies/TestPolicy_0001.xml

and sample request from:

> https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/trunk/commons/balana/modules/balana-core/src/test/resources/basic/3/requests/request_0001_02.xml

and getting an Indeterminate response from WSO2 identity server stating "Couldn't find AttributeDesignator attribute"

```
<Response xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17">
<Result>
<Decision>Indeterminate</Decision>
<Status>
<StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:missing-attribute"/>
<StatusMessage>Couldn't find AttributeDesignator attribute</StatusMessage>
<StatusDetail>
<MissingAttributeDetail AttributeId="http://kmarket.com/id/role" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" ></MissingAttributeDetail>
</StatusDetail>
</Status>
</Result>
</Response>
```

Not sure what i am missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If send the 'urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject' attribute in the request, this will be resolved. You can have a set of policies with sample requests and responses from here at as a series at my blog,http://pushpalankajaya.blogspot.com/2013/06/working-with-xacml-30-policies-for-fine.html